# Promise.all inside promise.all its a good practice for Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I don't know if a `promise.all` inside `promise.all` solution is a good practice or not. I'm not sure.

I need to get info from array of users, then with this info responses, i need to send message notification.

```
let userList = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']; //More data can arrive
let promises = userList.map((userKey,index)=>{
            return GetUserById(db.ref(`Users/${userKey}`));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(responses =>{
  let notificationPromises = responses.map((user)=>{
      sendNotification('message', user.token);
  });
  return Promise.all(notificationPromises)
}).then(()=>{
   //notifications were sent
   ...
};
```

Is it a good idea to solve it with `Promise.all` nested?

Comment: if that's the functionality you need, sure, why not?

Comment: Only thing I see is that this means you have to wait for all users, then wait for all notifications. You could just chain the notification off the user promise to begin with if you wanted, eg: `return GetUserById(...).then(user => sendNotification(...))`. But IMO what you have looks fine as well.

Comment: @KevinB you're righrt, i can include sending notification after getting the user. auch. more than 10 hours working do not let me think clearly, I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this will work, it's hard to see why this is a better choice than just calling `then()` on the first set of requests -- remember, `then()` also returns a promise.  This seems not only shorter, much clearer to me. It's very obvious that you are sending notifications to each user:

```
let userList = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']; //More data can arrive
let promises = userList.map((userKey,index)=>{
            return GetUserById(db.ref(`Users/${userKey}`))
            .then(user => sendNotification('message', user.token) )
});

Promise.all(promises)
.then(()=>{
    //notifications were sent
    // ...
});
```

p.s. in your code, you need to return something from the `map()` callback otherwise `notificationPromises` will be an array of empty values:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(responses =>{
    let notificationPromises = responses.map((user)=>{
        return sendNotification('message', user.token); //<< add return
    });
```

Comment: jajaja.. yeah... I mentioned same solution to @KevinB a moment ago. I've been working for a long time, I'll rest. thnks